# jQuery Mobile onSelect ... load dialog when radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

how would I start an onselect in jQuery Mobile when a radio button is chosen? When a user select a radio button I want page30.html (a dialog msgbox) to automatically load.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page29">
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">
        Back
    </a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="no-field-separator">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
            <legend>
            </legend>
            <input name="radiobuttons4" id="radio11" value="radio1" type="radio" />
            <label for="radio11">
                <span class="f_13">1 - </span>
            </label>
            <input name="radiobuttons4" id="radio13" value="radio13" type="radio" />
            <label for="radio13">
                <span class="f_13">2 - </span>
            </label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `data-role="dialog"` to page30's page container. i.e.

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="page30">
    ...
</div>
```

Then use this in your javascript.

```
$(document).on('change', '#radio11', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage('page30.html');
});
```

Comment: ok so does page30.hmtl exist in that same directory? Also what version of JQM are you using.

Comment: i'm using jqm 1.1.0 and yes page page30.html is in the same folder

Comment: found the solution. your example is correct but jqm doesn't like file:// I had to put the files on my server and it worked.

do I change all id's to "radio11" if I want the dialog box to show? will i have a conflict?

Comment: So you always want page30 to show no matter what radio? You can only have one id. Add a class instead perhaps or just use the `input[type=radio]` selector.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'radio1') {
        $('#somewhere').load('path/to/page30.html')
   }
})
```

Comment: was looking around, wouldn't it be best to detected if radio becomes "checked" to determine when the new page loads?

Comment: it detects the value of input, it's better to use a checkbox.